# Relative coordinates in DrawingBrush

Tags: wpf

I am somewhat confused about how relative coordinates work in WPF, especially in scenarios with DrawingBrushes.

Let's say I want to paint the background of a square area, which is flexible in it's size. I want to paint the background with a special "shape", let's say a kind of "T" laying on the side, with the vertical stroke going through the middle of the area.
Using relative coordinates (the size of the area is flexible), I came up with the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="722" Width="722" UseLayoutRounding="True">
<Window.Resources>
   
    <DrawingBrush x:Key="EdgeGrid">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <GeometryDrawing>
                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    <!-- draw a single T laying on the side -->
                    <GeometryGroup>
                        <!-- top to bottom -->
                        <LineGeometry StartPoint="0.5,0.0" EndPoint="0.5,1"/>
                        <!-- left to right -->
                        <LineGeometry StartPoint="0.5,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5"/>
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    <Pen Thickness="0.01" Brush="Black" />
                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
</Window.Resources>      
    <Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Rectangle Width="400" Height="400" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="{StaticResource EdgeGrid}">
    </Rectangle>

</Grid>
```

But the result I get looks like this:

[image: Output]
<sub>(source: [bilder-hochladen.net](http://www.bilder-hochladen.net/files/big/jf1u-1p-29ec.png))</sub>

Shouldn't the vertical stroke go right through the middle (X coordinate is 0.5)?
And also how can I set the pen thickness to be 1 or 2 pixels in relative mode?
Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that that there is nothing drawn on the left side of your `DrawingBrush`. Everything starts horizontally from 0.5 and is optimised to show only the party that you draw. In other words it it starts and ends with first/last drawn point

Comment: Aaah, the "BoundingBox" part in RelativeToBoundingBox is the bounding box of the drawing itself, not the one of the area to be painted. Now it starts to make sense again. Freaky stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to set the `ViewboxUnits` property of the DrawingBrush to `Absolute` (instead of the default `RelativeToBoundingBox`). The `Viewbox` would still be `(0,0,1,1)`.

See the [TileBrush Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970682(v=vs.100).aspx) article on MSDN for details about a brush's viewbox and viewport.

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="EdgeGrid" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0.5,0.0" EndPoint="0.5,1"/>
                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0.5,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5"/>
                </GeometryGroup>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen Thickness="0.01" Brush="Black" />
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

Of course this won't let you define stroke widths in pixels. Making the drawing in absolute coordinates and then putting the whole thing in a Viewbox won't also help much, because strokes would still be scaled.

In order to get a scalable drawing with fixed stroke width, you would have to use a Path element, where you set the `StrokeThickness` and `Data` properties and assign a ScaleTransform to the `Transform` property of the Geometry used as `Data`.

In your special case of drawing a centered, T-shaped figure with fixed stroke width, you may simply draw two (very long) Lines in a Canvas, where the coordinate origin is centered by putting the Canvas in a 2x2 Grid. You may even choose to have different strokes and stroke widths for the two Lines.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <Line Y1="-10000" Y2="10000" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        <Line X2="10000" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Aaah, I think now I understand how it is supposed to work. I have read the TileBrush documentation but, apparently, completely misinterpreted the ViewBox stuff. Specifically what the "BoundingBox" part in `RelativeToBoundingBox` refers to. But such things are bound to happen when the APIs are designed in a way that calls for setting the units to `Absolute` when all one wants are relative coordinates ;-)

Comment: I don't like the Canvas & Grid solution. It may work, but is ugly like hell.

Comment: I also do not quite understand how I should use that Path element you proposed. `DrawingBrush` is not accepting Paths, so I have to use `VisualBrush`, right? But then the `StrokeThickness` is scaled similar to the original problem, so I have not gained anything?

Comment: Basically, don't use a Brush at all when you want to scale geometries, but not the strokes they ary drawn with.

Answer (score 0):

To get vertical stroke right you need to do it like this:

```
<GeometryGroup>
     <!-- top to bottom -->
     <LineGeometry StartPoint="0.75,0.0"
                   EndPoint="0.75,1" />
     <!-- left to right -->
     <LineGeometry StartPoint="0.5,0.5"
                   EndPoint="1,0.5" />
</GeometryGroup>
```

But that won't help you with pen thickness. In general, if you want to scale a geometry - first create it using absolute coordinates you like (say in 0-100 range), then put that into ViewBox or use ScaleTransform, like this:

```
    <Viewbox Width="400"
             Height="400">
        <Path Stroke="Black"
              StrokeThickness="1">
            <Path.Data>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <!-- top to bottom -->
                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="75,0"
                                  EndPoint="75, 100" />
                    <!-- left to right -->
                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="50,50"
                                  EndPoint="100, 50" />
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Viewbox>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated! But why on Earth in coordinate system [0,1] do I need to use 0.75 to position things in the middle? Am I the only one who is not getting it?

Comment: And if I change the second line to also start  in the middle horizontally 
`<LineGeometry StartPoint="0.75,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5"/>` (I need a "T" laying on it's side), I get the same result as before?

Comment: And from your recommendation to use absolute coordinates it seems that all this relative stuff is not of much use in practical situations, right?

Comment: @Santik I see it's already explained in the answer above. And no, in general in WPF almost everything is done relative, not absolute. In case of Paths, as I said you can put them in ViewBox (or apply ScaleTransform) and they will scale to any size you need, so it's not really absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see how the proposed solution would look like.
Let's assume we want to show the shapes in a kind of grid and draw various shapes depending on the data (by selecting an appropriate DateTemplate). For simplicity, in this example, let's draw only one kind of shape (a cross, as in my initial question):

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="722" Width="722" UseLayoutRounding="True">

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding data}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="10" Rows="10">
                </UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>        
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="Cell">
                   <Path StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Blue" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <GeometryGroup>
                                <GeometryGroup.Transform>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=Cell, Path=ActualWidth}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=Cell, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                                </GeometryGroup.Transform>
                                <!-- top to bottom -->
                                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0.5,0.0" EndPoint="0.5,1"/>
                            </GeometryGroup>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <Path StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <GeometryGroup>
                                <GeometryGroup.Transform>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=Cell, Path=ActualWidth}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=Cell, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                                </GeometryGroup.Transform>
                                <!-- left to right -->
                                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5"/>
                            </GeometryGroup>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>    
    </ItemsControl>        
   </Window>
```

@Clemens Is this the solution you had in mind? Is this the correct way of doing it?
The only problem I have with the result is that the lines are blurry and there is even a break to be seen in the horizontal line. Is there any solution for this?

[image: blurry lines]

Comment: The problem with the blurry lines can be solved by turning antialiasing off for both `Paths` by setting attached property `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"`. So now only the problem with the "breaks" in the horizontal lines remain.

Comment: Ok, I figured out that one too at last! The size of the ItemsPanel (`UniformGrid`) has to be set to an integer multiply of the grid dimension, otherwise rounding errors (?) when scaling the Path's geometries are causing this strange artifacts. With this last (?) problem solved, I can accept @Clemens answer as the solution of the problem.